# How do I format copied cell text as number?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba formula that copies a value (which consists in a number) of a cell to another cell. When the number is with decimals (ex: 25,50), the result is ok, but when the number is without decimals (ex: 50), I get an error checking flag suggesting me to convert that cell to number.

I wouldn't have a problem with this error flagging, but I cannot use the result in a formula. For example, if I use `SUM(A:A)`, the formula adds all the numbers, except the flagged ones.

So far, I have tried pasting using the `.xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` property, without any success.

```
Sub Adauga()
Dim i As Range
Dim cellTaxa As Range

Set cellTaxa = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(1, -2) 'Here I set the range to the value of a cell that is related to the button I click. 

n = 2
Set i = Sheets("TJT DETERMINABILA").Cells(n, 10) 'Here I insert the first result
Do While i <> "" 'Here I find the next empty cell in the same column to insert the value.
    n = n + 1
    Set i = Sheets("TJT DETERMINABILA").Cells(n, 10)
Loop

cellTaxa.Copy 'Here I copy the cell
i.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Here I paste the cell. 

End Sub
```

I would like to be able to use the values that are pasted in the column I mentioned in the code with the `SUM` formula.
Thank you!

Comment: Adding `+ 0` to the end is an easy trick to convert text to numbers (given the text should be converted to a number)

Comment: @urdearboy    Where exactly should I put + 0 in the vba code? I am thinking about adding the following code: `cellTaxa = CellTaxa + 0`.

Comment: @urdearboy, I have tried adding the abovementioned code before `cellTaxa.Copy` but it didn't work. I still get the yellow excalamation mark.

Comment: Try `i = i + 0` after you paste. Or `i.value = i.value = 0`. You could also use `Text to Columns`

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The workaround was to put `cellTaxa = CellTaxa + 0. You were right.

Comment: @urdearboy Unlike on the Worksheet, there's no need for the `+0` in VBA.  You can simply do `cellTaxa=cellTaxa`. Of course, if the cell format is text, you may need to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @urdearboy has stated, an easy trick to convert text to numbers is to add `+0`.

In my case, I have added `cellTaxa = CellTaxa + 0` before the line `cellTaxa.Copy` and it has solved my issue.

Comment: With VBA, there's no need for the `+0`.  So long as the cell is not formatted as text, you can simply do `cellTaxa=cellTaxa` and a numeric string value will be converted to a number.